# What kind of tool has a thin, oddly-shaped blade inserted into a handle?

Tags: identify-a-tool

found it and really don't know where to start looking to identify it. it has no markings on it.
[image]

Comment: It is a bottle cap remover.  You slip the little notch under a bottle cap and ply off.  We did not have twist offs in the olden days.

Comment: It does look like it *might* be a bottle cap remover. David, can you measure it or take another picture of it next to a ruler? We could pair this question with the one about the can crusher.

Comment: Home-made paint can opener? The shank resembles that of a file; can't tell from the photo whether file teeth are present or not.

Comment: @crip659 it is to long to be bottle cap remover

Comment: @Ruskes   The length just makes it easier to remove caps.  The length is for shaken bottles.

Comment: @crip659 It seems too complicated for a bottle cap remover to me. If you know the bottle will spray everywhere, would you open it or wait a while until it won't spray? Even bottle cap openers for people with reduced strength don't have that length. And what is the rest of the form for? It doesn't seem thick enough to be a grill pan handle.

Comment: it's about 12" in length, i don't believe it to be a bottle opener..i thought maybe something to pull racks out of oven when hot, or hooking onto a cookie sheet. but cant find anything similar.

Comment: Could be an automotive window trim removing tool.

Answer (score 3):

Looks more like a bucket opener. Back in 'the days' a lot of buckets had metal lids with multiple bending tabs to be pried up before opening.

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly be used to relieve spring tension on a tensioner pulley for a car engine (for example).

There are usually idler pulleys that push against a belt to keep the proper tension on it, this could be used (with different hook shapes to fit different vehicles) to pull the tensioner loose so the belt can be removed.

It could also be used to pull an alternator to create the proper tension before the alternator is tightened into position to keep the tension.